# C# storing XML into string

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have a situation where I'm storing some XML into a string like so:

```
string searchXML = @"<Search order=""name""><Group conditions_operand=""all""><Condition model=""Company""><Attribute>id</Attribute><Operator>equals</Operator><Values><Value>" + variablenamehere + "</Value></Values></Condition></Group></Search>";
```

and I've noticed that it's storing this into the string with several escape characters included, for example if i inspect the string I see:

```
<Search order=\"name\"><Group conditions_operand=\"all\">
```

Is it actually storing the \ character in there?  If so how can I get rid of it as I do not think this is properly formatted XML.  I am using double quotes in the first place because I need to do that as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not storing the escape characters. That's just the way the debugger displays the string. If you type `searchXML` in the Immediate Window in Visual Studio, it should print out without the escape characters.

Comment: this is interesting, i checked the immediate window and still see      <Search order=\"name\"><Group conditions_operand=\"all\"><Condition model=\"Company\"><Attribute>id</Attribute><Operator>equals</Operator><Values><Value>0000000015</Value></Values></Condition></Group></Search>"

Comment: @testercoder1 interesting. You're right. Either way it's not storing the escape characters, it's just a debugger display thing.